# After Animation JSON load

Tags: android, json

I am new in android development.

I am developing an app in which I have to add intro slides after animation end but the problem is, I have to get data(Image and title) from json and show in into slides. I am getting data but unable to update slides.

I have tried to call JSON class from `animationEnd()` but getting null object reference.

Please help me. I will so thankfull.

Here is my code.

MainActivity

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements 
    Animation.AnimationListener {

    ImageView img;
    Animation animFadeIn;

    StringBuffer finalString = new StringBuffer();

    private TextView title1, title2, title3;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        animFadeIn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.fade_in);


        animFadeIn.setAnimationListener(this);

        img.startAnimation(animFadeIn);
        //img.startAnimation(animZoomIn);

        title1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_title1);
        title2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_title2);
        title3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_title3);

        //new JSONTask().execute("https://www.prepforsure.com/engine/admin/mobileapi.php?action=addinto_api");

    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

        new JSONTask().execute("https://www.prepforsure.com/engine/admin/mobileapi.php?action=addinto_api");
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

        Intent i = new Intent(this, IntroActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);

        new JSONTask().execute("https://www.prepforsure.com/engine/admin/mobileapi.php?action=addinto_api");


    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

    }


    public class JSONTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            HttpURLConnection connection = null;
            BufferedReader reader = null;

            try {
                URL url = new URL(params[0]);
                connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                connection.connect();

                InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();

                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

                String line = "";

                StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {

                    buffer.append(line);
                }
                String finalJSON = buffer.toString();

                //Get JSON Array

                JSONArray parentArray = new JSONArray(finalJSON);


                for (int i = 0; i < parentArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject firstObject = parentArray.getJSONObject(i);

                    String title = firstObject.getString("TITLE");

                    finalString.append(title + "\n");

                }
                //return buffer.toString();
                return finalString.toString();


            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if (connection != null) {
                    connection.disconnect();
                }
                try {

                    if (reader != null) {
                        reader.close();
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            title1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_title1);
            title1.setText(result);

        }
    }

}
```

IntroActivity

```
 public class IntroActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private ViewPagerAdapter viewPagerAdapter;
    private LinearLayout dotsLayout;
    private TextView[] dots;
    private int[] layouts;
    private Button btnSkip, btnNext;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_intro);


        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);


        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.intro_view_pager);
        dotsLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layoutDots);
        btnSkip = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_skip);
        btnNext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_next);

        layouts = new int[]{
                R.layout.slide1,
                R.layout.slide2,
                R.layout.slide3};


        // adding bottom dots
        addBottomDots(0);

        viewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter();
        viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);
        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(viewPagerPageChangeListener);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
    }

    public void btnSkipClick(View v) {

        launchHomeScreen();

    }

    public void btnNextClick(View v) {
        // checking for last page
        // if last page home screen will be launched


        int current = getItem(1);
        if (current < layouts.length) {
            // move to next screen
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(current);


        } else {
            launchHomeScreen();
        }
    }


    ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener viewPagerPageChangeListener = new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            addBottomDots(position);

            // changing the next button text 'NEXT' / 'GOT IT'
            if (position == layouts.length - 1) {
                // last page. make button text to GOT IT
                btnNext.setText(getString(R.string.start));
                btnSkip.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else {
                // still pages are left
                btnNext.setText(getString(R.string.next));
                btnSkip.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {

        }
    };


    private void addBottomDots(int currentPage) {
        dots = new TextView[layouts.length];

        dotsLayout.removeAllViews();
        for (int i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
            dots[i] = new TextView(this);
            dots[i].setText(Html.fromHtml("&#8226;"));
            dots[i].setTextSize(35);
            dots[i].setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.dot_inactive));
            dotsLayout.addView(dots[i]);
        }

        if (dots.length > 0)
            dots[currentPage].setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.dot_active));
    }


    private int getItem(int i) {
        return viewPager.getCurrentItem() + i;
    }

    private void launchHomeScreen() {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, Welcome_Activity.class));
        finish();
    }

    public class ViewPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
        private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;


        public ViewPagerAdapter() {

        }

        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
            layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            View view = layoutInflater.inflate(layouts[position], container, false);
            container.addView(view);

            return view;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return layouts.length;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object obj) {
            return view == obj;
        }


        @Override
        public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
            View view = (View) object;
            container.removeView(view);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: can you elaborate your question??

Comment: Yes. I have to show intro screen after animation end. I have three slides having images1/2/3 and title1/2/3 which I have to fetch from json. onAnimationEnd() m calling introActivity for showing the slides... I am asking where should i call JSONTask class to get data in slides?

Comment: So basically your animation is **SPLASH SCREEN** kind of stuff and once it gets over you wanna go to another activity and show the intro screen right?

Comment: Right. And have to get images and title from json. so how should i call introActivity and JSONTask both and set images and title after end of animation?

Comment: call JsonTask from IntroActivity then. Is it mandatory to call it from initial class??